# c++ Reading a JSON Scene File

Tags: c++, regex, json

Im using JSON for a "scene" file for my engine; it looks like this:

```
{
"thorium": {
"name" : "JustAnotherMap",
"desc" : "A Map file",

"actor": {
"type" : "Volume",
"name" : "m_pActor1",
"rotation" : "0.0 0.0 0.0",
"position" : "0.0 0.0 0.0"
}   
}
}
```

So i want to be able to read this and for example, create the object VolumeActor with a name m_pActor1 etc. Is this a regex job? I've seen a lot of conflicting information so im not so sure how to approach this.

Comment: I suggest using [Boost property tree](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/property_tree.html) Library instead of regular expressions. It has a nice [JSON parser](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_propertytree/parsers.html#boost_propertytree.parsers.json_parser).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON syntax contains balanced curly braces and this makes it a [context-free language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar). Regular expressions are a tool for parsing simpler languages known as [regular languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_grammar). See [Chomsky hierarchy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy).

That said, most regular expression engines in use today include extensions which make them more powerful and allow them to parse languages which are not strictly regular. This includes parsing of balanced curly braces.

However, the regular expression to do the job will be ugly, may end up relying on non-portable features and will be a nightmare to maintain in the face of changing structure of your JSON data.

You should use a proper JSON parser, e.g. [the one from Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_propertytree/parsers.html#boost_propertytree.parsers.json_parser).

Comment: So should i make a Struct for each actor and then use an iterator to go through the ptree and if "actor" is the node name then create the struct?